# x12 turtle beach hurts, any advice?

Tags: troubleshooting, headphones

After around 25 min it start hurts my jaws, if I use it more than that it really hurts which makes them unusable.

I'm trying to soften the padding and the bridge.
Any tip / suggestion how to fix / workaround this issue?

[image]

Comment: Henny Youngman: The patient says, “Doctor, it hurts when I do this.” The doctor says, “Then don’t do that.”

Comment: Maybe you stay using them to loudly already at the beginning? Do you experience similar issue with other earphones? Does the problem depends on what are you listening to?

Comment: @Máté - no, it just put to much pressure on the ear bones, which blocks blood pressure, which in time ~25 min start to hurt badly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a software question, I'm afraid, and not related to SU.

However - try to:

1. Stop using it.
2. Switch to a different headset.
3. Run around the house praying for the headset G-O-D.

Comment: U R right, deleting question...
But before deleting, where is T right place 2 post it?

Comment: BTW - I've read that U can put it on a basketball over a week or so and the bridge will soften, so - there are workarounds that super users might want to know about..

Comment: I'll tell you what - try it. If it works - answer the question yourself:)

Comment: And I'd imagine stackexchange's not the best place. Try [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/)

Comment: ותזכור שלא מעט מאתנו ישראלים כאן, אז גם עברית זה בסדר:)

Comment: 10x :-), shouldn't there be a subject like gaming-accessories / something like that?

Comment: Not that I know of....check the SE list for something of the sorts.